# i am facing problem in my ionic app when i build it

Tags: node.js, npm

hi  can you  help me please! i write (ionic start app) and run
when the (npm.cmd i) run the problem show:
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ytYKwd1WQSBST07nwPFjH'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAM-TEC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-24T16_07_36_464Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

```
    npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Did you look at the log?

Comment: I am a beginner, I downloaded it, but did not understand

Comment: i am update npm and the result is new error

Comment: npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SAM-TEC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-27T22_02_24_579Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.